# JSON parsing error. Volley cannot convert String to JSON array

Tags: php, android, html, android-volley

I have a PHP file which makes `JSONArray` from some data on my database. I had this on my localhost (using easy php) and it was working well.
After I have transferred it to a real host I am getting an error:

> Org.json.jsonexception: Value ... script of type java.lang.String
>   cannot be converted to JSONObject

**My json looks like:**

```
{
    "chemData": [{
        "ID": "1",
        "TYPE": "AD_SOLVENTBASE",
        "COMPANY": "MORCHEM",
        "SOLIDC": "65.000",
        "GRAMNEED": "3.200",
        "SOLUSE": "0.450",
        "PRICE": "15000"
    }, {
        "ID": "2",
        "TYPE": "AD_SOLVENTLESS",
        "COMPANY": "MORCHEM",
        "SOLIDC": "100.000",
        "GRAMNEED": "2.300",
        "SOLUSE": "0.000",
        "PRICE": "15000"
    }, {
        "ID": "3",
        "TYPE": "HEATSEAL_PS",
        "COMPANY": "BUJAN",
        "SOLIDC": "25.000",
        "GRAMNEED": "5.000",
        "SOLUSE": "0.250",
        "PRICE": "26000"
    }, {
        "ID": "4",
        "TYPE": "COLDSEAL",
        "COMPANY": "AZARAN_BASPAR",
        "SOLIDC": "50.000",
        "GRAMNEED": "3.000",
        "SOLUSE": "0.000",
        "PRICE": "14000"
    }, {
        "ID": "5",
        "TYPE": "INK",
        "COMPANY": "BEHROFARAN",
        "SOLIDC": "37.000",
        "GRAMNEED": "2.000",
        "SOLUSE": "0.450",
        "PRICE": "12500"
    }, {
        "ID": "6",
        "TYPE": "EASYPEEL",
        "COMPANY": "BUJAN",
        "SOLIDC": "25.000",
        "GRAMNEED": "5.000",
        "SOLUSE": "0.250",
        "PRICE": "50000"
    }],
    "filmData": [{
        "id": "1",
        "Film Type": "PE",
        "Density": "0.9200",
        "Price": "6000"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "Film Type": "CPP",
        "Density": "0.9200",
        "Price": "9500"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "Film Type": "PET",
        "Density": "1.4100",
        "Price": "12000"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "Film Type": "BOPP",
        "Density": "0.9300",
        "Price": "9500"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "Film Type": "Al",
        "Density": "2.7400",
        "Price": "12000"
    }, {
        "id": "6",
        "Film Type": "BOPP MET",
        "Density": "0.9300",
        "Price": "10000"
    }],
    "cost": [{
        "ID": "1",
        "WORKERPART": "720",
        "ENERGYPART": "80",
        "BANKNUZUL": "1700",
        "TRANSFERIN": "100",
        "TRANSFERTO": "0",
        "PACKING": "60",
        "WASTE": "4",
        "COMMISION": "80",
        "SOLVENTPRICE": "4300"
    }]
}
```

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code, never post it as an answer if it's not a solution to the question

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this code:

```
        try {
        JSONObject rootObj = new JSONObject(yourJson);

        JSONArray chemData = rootObj.getJSONArray("chemData");
        JSONArray filmData = rootObj.getJSONArray("filmData");
        JSONArray cost = rootObj.getJSONArray("cost");

        for (int i = 0; i < chemData.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = chemData.getJSONObject(i);

            String id = obj.getString("ID");
            obj.getString("TYPE");
            String company = obj.getString("COMPANY");
            obj.getString("SOLIDC");
            obj.getString("GRAMNEED");
            obj.getString("SOLUSE");
            obj.getString("PRICE");

            Log.d("testing", id + "  " + company);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < filmData.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = filmData.getJSONObject(i);

            String id = obj.getString("id");
            obj.getString("Film Type");
            obj.getString("Density");
            String price = obj.getString("Price");

            Log.d("testing", id + "  " + price);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < cost.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = cost.getJSONObject(i);

            String id = obj.getString("ID");
            obj.getString("WORKERPART");
            obj.getString("ENERGYPART");
            obj.getString("BANKNUZUL");
            obj.getString("TRANSFERIN");
            obj.getString("TRANSFERTO");
            obj.getString("PACKING");
            String waste = obj.getString("WASTE");
            obj.getString("COMMISION");
            obj.getString("SOLVENTPRICE");

            Log.d("testing", id + "  " + waste);
        }

    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You should probably create three pojo classes to store your data in an ArrayList of type *yourPojo*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a code something like that. But it is too long.

Comment: @user97 It is all necessary to parse an object. But look into Gson or Jackson libraries to help reduce that. Also, Retrofit can be used instead of Volley to also parse JSON

Answer (score -1):

This is the parsing part in start:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

    JSONArray [] jsonArrays = new JSONArray[response.length()];
    try {
        jsonArrays [0] = response.getJSONArray("chemData");
        jsonArrays [1] = response.getJSONArray("filmData");
        jsonArrays [2] = response.getJSONArray("cost");

    }catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```